# Possible to set a selector for a ListView's cacheColorHint?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, selector, drawable

I'd like to set a selector as the colorCacheHint of a ListView:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="@color/selector_background" />
```

But referencing this as the cache color hint has no effect.

Is it impossible to have a cacheColorHint change depending on the state of the ListView?  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't end up going through the source code, but I empirically agree with @LuxuryMode that it truly isn't possible to set the cache color hint to a selector.

I ended up with this added to `refreshDrawableState` of my custom View.  The trick is the combination of `getColorStateList` and `getColorForState` to allow you to apply the correct color from a selector.

```
    ColorStateList listBackground = view.getContext().getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.list_background);
    int color = listBackground.getColorForState(view.getDrawableState(),listBackground.getDefaultColor());

    try {
        view.setCacheColorHint(color);
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        //Early versions of Android have a bug in setCacheColorHint
        // http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12840
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont believe you can have a selector used for the cache color hint. what exactly would these 
different states be? Makes sense to have states for the individual items, e.g. pressed, focused, etc, but why would this make sense for the ListView itself?

**EDIT**

Presumably you want to switch the look of things based on some of your own (domain) logic as opposed to having the UI changes depend on the predefined states that are used in defining selectors. In other words, if you used a selector as cache color hint, which one of the states would you be hoping to use? android:state_pressed, android:state_focused, android:state_hovered, android:state_selected, etc? I think you need to simply set the cache color hint based directly based on your logic:

```
int cacheColorRes = myState == foo? R.drawable.something : R.drawable.somethingElse;
mView.setCacheColorHint(cacheColorRes)
```

Comment: A sensible question.  But I have custom states for my app to enable theme switching.  I can switch the background from white to black.  Obviously, it's very important for me to switch the cache color hint too.

Comment: I am using custom states (eg `app:state_dark`) and for other views and attributes, all I have to do is say `view.setDark(true)` and the background, text color, etc change appropriately.  I would like to achieve this cache color change via XML too.

Comment: This is a bit above my pay grade ;) If you want to go ahead and set some theming, etc at a certain point in time, then it doesn't seem like you want a layer-list/selector type construct. A selector makes sense when there's gonna be repeated and quick changes in some drawable. Sounds like what you need is a bunch of themes and then swap them out. Obviously in your themes, you can define different cacheColorHints to go along with whatever else makes sense in the theming.

Comment: I do have themes, but you need to set an Android theme only when your activity is launched. :)  In my case, the "theme change" needs to happen repeatedly, during runtime, just like you say.  Thanks for your help, I'll post if I figure anything out!